# ORC.Prims nuget package is deprecated

Tags: catel

The ORC.Prism nuget package is deprecated.
What do we need to do to maintain out applications which are  using this package?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1. Support the developers via open collective so they can keep supporting this package
2. Fork the package and maintain it yourself

Catel and Prism are both being actively maintained, it's just the glue in between that is no longer being maintained because the Catel / WildGums teams haven't used Prism for a long time.